# Accessing class attribute with multiple values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on some extra practice on javascript as I always feel like I'm not confident enough with it but I stumbled upon a problem I can't think or find a way to solve it.

The step is to add the class attributes of:

```
class="sliderInput first; last; inc;style"
```

That is not the problem but later they tell you to do this:

> Using the class name structure described above add class attributes to
>   the 10 input boxes on the Web Form. For the red,green, and blue input
>   boxes, the input values range from 255 down to 0 in the increments of
>   -1 units. Use a value of 1 for style. For the opacity input boxes input values range from 100 down to 0 in the increments of -5. Use a
>   value of 2 for style. For the z-index boxes, the input values range
>   from 1 to 2 in an increment of 1 unit. Use the value of 3 for style.

Now can you put these values to the class attribute and access that or what do you get from that statement? If I had to say first = 255 for an example I don't think you can set a value to a class attribute and look for the value field of that.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: The block quote above is execute so later on you can create custom properties for a object which creates input,first,last,inc, and style and correlate the values stored within each element that they suggest you to input.

The entire problem was to be given a bland webpage with the 5 sliders and two boxes. As the sliders increase and decrease you can modify the boxes css attributes of: Red,Green, Blue, Opacity, and zIndex. They tell you to add the class attributes of:

```
class="sliderInput first; last; inc;style"
```

to these input boxes:

```
 <label>Red</label>
     <input id="red1" value="255"/>
     <br />
  <label>Green</label>
     <input id="green1" value="255"/>
     <br />
  <label>Blue</label>
     <input id="blue1" value="255"/>
     <br />
  <label>Opacity</label>
      <input id="opacity1" value="100"/>
      <br />
  <label>Z-Index</label>
     <input id="zIndex1" value="1"/>
```

Then the next step is to follow this chunk of text:

> Using the class name structure described above add class attributes to the 10 input boxes on the Web Form. For the red,green, and blue input boxes, the input values range from 255 down to 0 in the increments of -1 units. Use a value of 1 for style. For the opacity input boxes input values range from 100 down to 0 in the increments of -5. Use a value of 2 for style. For the z-index boxes, the input values range from 1 to 2 in an increment of 1 unit. Use the value of 3 for style.

And then create an class constructor for each widget bar(pretty much each input box) that has five properties of: Input,first,last,inc,style

Then have those 5 properties to correlate with the values you inserted into each input box with the proper values.

Comment: Read this 3 times and still having hard time making sense of it. Classes can't have `;` in them.  `style` is typically a different attribute whose values control display. The value explanation is hard to understand and has inconsistencies in it. Explain your understanding of what the objective is here and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'll edit the original text to clarify what the objective of the blockquote is exactly.

Comment: Is this really original text? Looks like a very bad translation which makes little sense...

Comment: Word for word of the text unfortunately

Comment: Still haven't explained exactly what it is you are trying to do in a clear and concise manner including any real world examples. I think you may be trying to store values in the html for which you could use `data-` attributes that can use any arbitrary names but still not sure

Comment: I think you need to re-invent this whole question ... starting at the highest level objective then explaining the issues you have with steps achieving it.

Comment: The project is pretty much a basic web page that has two boxes. There are 5 inputs to each box which are red, green, blue, opacity, and z-index so pretty much you can play with the RGB and certain css effects of  these boxes. While that gives you background knowledge of what these values correlate to with the textbook problem I'm not sure if that gives you any further information to what they are referring to as there example of the class quote is an issue from the start.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for working with me here I'm sorry if I haven't given as much detail as needed to fully understand the question. While I understand the objective the issues I have with this problem is the example they give with the class attribute doesn't make sense with the values they tell you to input. Obviously a class attribute can't hold a value and that is what is throwing me off.

Comment: OK sounds like you over complicated the original part of the question. Change your ID's to classes. Then use those classes to add event listeners for `change` event. Then you can use jQuery css() method to adjust the style properties of the boxes depending on which slider class is changed. Similar to how a colorpicker works

Comment: ALso I think you may have confused *javascript class function* ( as in "widget class constructor") with html element class

Comment: Not sure who's article or blog you have read this from but there is an error in the suggested implementation as far as I am aware they are suggesting to manipulate the rgba value's by the input slides but they or you have said opacity has values from 0 - 100; both in filter:opacity; and rgba the opacity value only goes from 0 up to a maximum of 1.. So suggest you re read the instructions and refactor your question maybe explaining it a bit better and adding some more code.